# MySql Bulk(ish) Insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm attempting to do a "bulk" insert with the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `order_status_histories` VALUES ('3602','52efabe9-5f8c-4512-a994-3227c63dd20e','1','','Order recieved','2014-02-03 16:47:05','2014-02-03 16:47:05'),('3603','52eff713-54fc-4be0-9389-68d5c63dd20e','1','','Order recieved','2014-02-03 22:07:47','2014-02-03 22:07:47'),('3604','52effd1a-bc14-4095-97fd-6d46c63dd20e','1','','Order recieved','2014-02-03 22:33:30','2014-02-03 22:33:30')
```

However, it is failing, because the first column in the table is `recordID`, and does not exist in the insert statement.

How can I get around this issue?

Comment: You're going to have to add the list of fields into your INSERT - `INSERT INTO table (field1, field2) VALUES ('value1', 'value2')` and so on.

Comment: is recordID is primary key and auto incremented ?

Comment: `recordID` is primary key and auto-incremented

Comment: use NULL for auto-increment column

Comment: you can put null as the recordID in insert

Comment: @andrewsi can you post that as the answer.  I did that and it worked... 3000+ records, but only had to specify the columns right before the `VALUES`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use

```
INSERT INTO `order_status_histories` VALUES (....)
```

you need to pass each value that the table structure requires, in the correct order. You can omit fields from the values if they have a default value in the table structure.

Most of the time, it's better to explicitly list the fields that you want to insert to - if nothing else, it means that if the table structure changes, you won't need to re-write your SQL statements. Try changing your SQL statement so it's structured as:

```
INSERT INTO `order_status_histories` (field1, field2, ....) VALUES ('value1', 'value2', ....)
```

Comment: Exactly. It's kind of like shooting the ONE golf ball and hope it lands into all 18 holes; at the same time and at night. ;-) **+1**